# When is a slot created in the Stellar Consensus Protocol?

Tags: consensus, scp

At what time during the protocol is a unique slot created for the nodes to vote on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

slot is simply a ledger number in Stellar implementation.
Once previous ledger closed nodes start by proposing candidates for the next "slot" and then vote on it.

Some relevant info can be found [here](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/src/herder/readme.md)

> **key implementation details**
>
> The Herder considers a ledger number to be a "slot" in the SCP protocol, and transaction set hashes (along with close-time and base-fee) to be the sort of "value" that it is attempting to agree on for each "slot".

Comment: Would that be my account number or the transaction sequence number? Or is it tracking a request on its own?